# Excluding and Reimporting a Maven Dependency with Different Version

Tags: java, maven

This example is a hypothetical scenario based on a real-world problem. Consider a block taken from a *pom.xml* file as given below. In this scenario, I want to exclude **artifact-b** dependency from **artifact-a** and reimport it with a different version. Obviously, excluded **artifact-b** version is not equal to `${product2.version}`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.product1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
    <version>${product1.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.company.product2</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.product2</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
    <version>${product2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Thus, when `mvn install` command is executed for the final application, I will only have the **artifact-b** with `${product2.version}` under the folder where the application stores the jars collected from its dependencies.

This is the expected behaviour for my module, but does it also mean that the methods in **artifact-a** jar will now make calls to the **artifact-b** jar with `${product2.version}`? If so (which is what I expect since target repository does not include the excluded version), what happens if the called method in **artifact-b** is different in the new version? Does it only check method signatures or are there other factors that can cause compilation/runtime errors?

Comment: First wrong assumption: You won't have any of the artifacts in your `target`  directory only the resulting jar of your pom project which uses `artifact-a` and `artifact-b` as dependency. Furthermore an exclusion in such case is not needed cause the distance of your project and the `artifact-b` will decide that you will use `artifact-b` with version `product2.version`...

Comment: There is an executable module and it collects all dependencies and creates a runnable project. I will fix that part in my question.

Comment: Does that change something? How do you collect the dependencies?

Comment: Before the update, I skipped the details and just wrote as all jar files the module uses will be under the target folder after the install command. In reality, the module only has itself in the target folder and all jar files that are used by the application will be under the lib folder of the actual application.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. By which plugin/tool do you achieve this? But it sounds like a job for maven-assembly-plugin...

Comment: maven-assembly-plugin, correct.

Comment: Than you don't need the exclusion as already mentioned etc. and no install command etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as khmarbaise said, the exclusion is unnecessary.

Secondly, increasing the library version can cause all kinds of problems. The compile time problems are mainly method signatures or missing classes, but at runtime, anything can happen, depending on the changes made in the source code of that library.

You can just hope that the maintainers of the library tried to keep everything backwards compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a case that causes problems when I remove the exclusions but this is a very big project and I am not able to share. That being said, what I assume is in most cases exclusions are unnecessary but it is not guaranteed. Secondly, I am perfectly aware that increasing the library version is not a good practice and can cause problems but my hands are tied for time being and all I can do is to make sure the application works correctly.

Comment: In your case, exclusions are always unnecessary. You can easily check this by running `mvn dependency:list` with and without your exclusion, and you will get the exact same result.

Comment: And I don't say that you should not increase the library version, but you need to test thoroughly whether anything breaks.